# Check if filename has timestamp

Tags: linux, shell-script

I need a shell script that checks whether my filename has timestamp. If yes, it should proceed to next step otherwise append timestamp to the filename.

Comment: Do you expect one kinda timestamp pattern or various patterns ?

Comment: Can you give example: I am assuming that you mean that the file name ends with a date e.g. `a name-2018-02-01`, but I am probably wrong.

Comment: yes...the filename should end with a date

Comment: Please **[edit] your question** to include the information rather than putting it in the comments. You've still not explained what the timestamp should look like. Examples are really useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

a="afile.txt"
sometimestamp="$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
if [[ $a =~ *"${sometimestamp}"* ]]; then 
   echo "Do something"; 
else 
   mv "$a" "${a}.${sometimestamp}"; 
fi
```

`sometimestamp="$(date ....)"` in the script can be changed to the timestamp that you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a `2018-02-01` is given by this regex:

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

Using that in a regex match will tell you if the filename match:

```
#!/bin/bash
f=filetotest.txt
regex='[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'

if [[ $f =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "File $f has a timestamp"
else
    mv -i "$f" "$f$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
fi
```

If the timestamp must be at the end of the filename use this regex instead:

```
[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$
```

(Note the `$` for end of line match)